# SQL filtering multiple columns based on various values (performed in R (dbi/odbc))

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I am working with an SQL script in the R environment, using packages ODBC/DBI to connect to the server:

```
original_file <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "DenodoODBC Unicode(x64)",
                      Server = "removed",
                      Database = "name",
                      UID = "removed",
                      PWD = "removed"
                      Authentication = "removed")



  new_file <-
  DBI::dbGetQuery(original_file,
                  "SELECT a.patient_id, a.code_01_cd, a.code_02_cd, a.code_03_cd, a.code_04_cd, a.code_05_cd, 
                  a.code_06_cd, a.code_07_cd, a.code_08_cd, a.code_09_cd, a.code_10_cd, a.code_11_cd, 
                  a.code_12_cd, a.code_13_cd, a.code_14_cd, a.code_15_cd, a.code_16_cd, a.code_17_cd, 
                  a.code_18_cd, a.code_19_cd, a.code_20_cd, a.code_21_cd, a.code_22_cd, a.code_23_cd, 
                  a.code_24_cd, a.code_25_cd, a.code_01_type_cd, b.patient_id, b.admit_date
                  FROM name.table1 is a
                  INNER JOIN name.table2 b
                  ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
                  WHERE (a.code_01_cd LIKE 'M10%' OR a.code_01_cd LIKE 'N850%' OR a.code_01_cd LIKE 'X500%' OR a.code_01_cd LIKE 'V100%')
                  AND admit_date >= '2020-01-01')
```

I need to filter the dataset using 25 different columns (a.code_01_cd to a.code_25_cd) with the various values that START WITH with character values ('M10', 'N850', 'X500", etc.). How can I modify the SQL script to filter the data based on the specified multiple values using the 25 code columns?

I am familiar with arrays with SAS, but I don't necessarily know how to go about applying that to SQL script. I couldn't find solutions online to answer my specific question.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your table design is not very good. You shouldn't have 25 identical columns, instead unpivot your table into a long skinny design, possibly with a secondary related table using a foreign key

Comment: There is no 'automated' way to do this; you just simply add all those to the WHERE condition ; it is a one-off activity, building the SQL string in a spreadsheet or in a good text editor (like NotePad++) would make it easier.

Comment: the time it took you to type the question, you would've finished. you could do something clever like an array of name => where condition values and then concat them together, but that still won't avoid the typing them in

Comment: @Charlieface, I agree that in general data like this _"in motion"_ might do better in a longer format, but I disagree that a database should always be stored that way. While longer formats can be useful, there is also utility (and at times _benefit_) from storing it in a wider format like above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to automate it where you don't have to type all variable names.

Reproducible setup for testing:

```r
# con <- dbConnect(...)
fakedata <- data.frame(patient_id="Z", code_01_cd="A", code_02_cd="B", code_03_cd="C")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", fakedata)
```

Get the known fields and filter out just the ones we need. I'm looking for `code_`, you may need to make that more or less specific.

```r
fields <- grep("code_", DBI::dbListFields(con, "mytable"), value = TRUE)
fields
# [1] "code_01_cd" "code_02_cd" "code_03_cd"
```

Setup the known values to search across *all* of those:

```r
values <- c("M10%", "N850%", "X500%", "V100%")
```

I'll set up using [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) (though one could brute-force this without doing it that way). In general, parameterized queries protect against ansi issues, programming mistakes, etc, which may lead to inadvertent SQL injection.

```r
qmarks <- rep(paste0("a.", fields, " LIKE ?"), each=length(values))
params <- rep(values, times = length(fields))
qmarks
#  [1] "a.code_01_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_01_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_01_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_01_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_02_cd LIKE ?"
#  [6] "a.code_02_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_02_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_02_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_03_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_03_cd LIKE ?"
# [11] "a.code_03_cd LIKE ?" "a.code_03_cd LIKE ?"
params
#  [1] "M10%"  "N850%" "X500%" "V100%" "M10%"  "N850%" "X500%" "V100%" "M10%"  "N850%" "X500%" "V100%"
```

Note that the `"code_*"` repeats through `length(values)` repetitions of each before moving on to the next, and `values` cycles through them rapidly. (I prepended `"a."` since you aliased your table as `a`.)

From here, we form the query and execute it:

```r
qry <- paste("select * from mytable a where (", paste(qmarks, collapse = " OR "), ")")
qry
# [1] "select * from mytable a where ( a.code_01_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_01_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_01_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_01_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_02_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_02_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_02_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_02_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_03_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_03_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_03_cd LIKE ? OR a.code_03_cd LIKE ? )"
res <- dbGetQuery(con, qry, params = as.list(params))
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thank you so much for your input and suggestions! When I try to run the following line:

fakedata <- data.frame(patient_id="Z", code_01_cd="A", code_02_cd="B", code_03_cd="C")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", fakedata)

I get the following error code: 
"Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1594:   % ?: ERROR: The user does not have CREATE privileges on the database 'name'
java.sql.SQLException: The user does not have CREATE privileges on the database 'name';
Error while executing the query".

Any suggestions?

Comment: (1) You have real data, you have no need to create that temporary data. It was only included so that others could play with this if desired. You should use your real table name, your real data. (2) If you do need to create tables (not required for everything from `fields` on down), then talk to your DBA, there's nothing to be done without system admin access. Does that clarify my answer?